# Ember Responsive iFrame component

Tags: iframe, ember.js

I'm embedding a PPT into my app, so I'd like a responsive iFrame. Can't get this working with the CSS based approached I've looked at [here](http://embedresponsively.com/).

I'm thinking the best way would be just to make a simple component with height and width properties. Can I make these computed properties / observers that listen and update on the browser resize?

Or would I need to create a resize event and update the properties on the event?

A little code example would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a `CSS` based approach, but you can use a component and use the resize event. Basically you would add the event listeners to `window` in your `didInsertElement` hook, and remove them in your `willDestroyElement` hook. Just use `jQuery`'s `.on()` and `.off()`.

```
onResize() {
    // do whatever you want to calculate your values
    set(this, 'my-frame-with', ...);
},
init() {
    set(this, 'boundOnResize', get(this, 'onResize').bind(this));
},
didInsertElement() {
    jQuery(window).on('resize', get(this, 'boundOnResize'));
},
willDestroyElement() {
    jQuery(window).off('resize', get(this, 'boundOnResize'));
}
```

You can not use computed properties for this because they need to depend on observable properties. This will not work for plain JS properties, because this in an ember functionality. So you need to kind of *wrap* them like this.